# nginx manage local servers depends on income domain name

Tags: dns, nginx

I have a few applications that are running localy in defferents ports, how can I configure NGINX server for forwarding request from port 80 to my application depends on income domain name. For example 2 local apps named 'app1' on port 8181 , and if request comes from `http://app1.com` - nginx forwards to `http://localhost:8181`

I've looked at nginx docs, I ask for your examples if someone did this.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), my method is to first configure the following reverse proxy settings in a new file called `/etc/nginx/reverse-proxy.conf`:

```
# Serve / from local http server.
# Just add the following to individual vhost configs:
# proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;

proxy_pass_header Server;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
proxy_connect_timeout 10;
proxy_read_timeout 10;
```

Then, for each reverse proxy I'm configuring, I add an appropriately-named configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` with the following:

```
server {
    server_name app1.com;
    server_name www.app1.com;
    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/reverse-proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8181/;
    }
}
```

You can create as many `server` blocks as you like and point them at different local (or even remote) application servers. You can also add `location` blocks to serve different URLs within the same domain statically, or from different local application servers.

(You can also just roll all the configuration into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but I find it easier to separate configuration out into multiple files.)

Comment: @Timopheym sorry, I only just saw your comment – thanks; I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this easily by following [this tutorial](https://allaboutghost.com/how-to-proxy-port-80-to-2368-for-ghost-with-nginx/).

Create a new file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` called `your-domain.com.conf` and put this in it:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-domain.conf.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
}
```

Then restart nginx

`sudo service nginx restart`