# how to make two different domains on the same server point to two different port by default

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, dns, server

I used Nginx to create server block on my VPS. So now I can access both myname.com and myname.me. The problem is I am using both php and node.js on my server. So I want that when I enter myname.com as url it uses port 80 by default and when I type myname.me it directs to port 3000 which is used by my node server instead of typing myname.me:3000.

Please let me know if my description isn't clear!

Thank you!

Comment: @HPierce Thank you very much! the second answer in that link solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

For your use case, just change your server blocks to be like this

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name     myname.com;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass      http://localhost:80;
                proxy_read_timeout      90;
                proxy_redirect  http://localhost:80;
        }
}

server {
        listen  80;
        server_name     myname.me;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass      http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_read_timeout      90;
                proxy_redirect  http://localhost:3000;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, which file should contain this? cuz i have two files one is etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myname.com and the other is etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myname.me

Comment: You can add this to either one of those files, but best way is to use individual blocks for individual files.

Comment: it gives me an error when i tried to do service nginx restart: invalid parameter "http://localhost:3000" and i also tried to replace localhost with my ip address and I got the same error

Comment: Try it now, updated with proxy headers

Comment: I followed the second answer of this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546792/nginx-manage-local-servers-depends-on-income-domain-name and it worked! Very close to your answer! Thank you!